# What is the IE equivalent for webkit overflow scrolling : touch

Tags: internet-explorer, css, webkit, touch

What is the IE equivalent css property for `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch` property for touch devices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[-ms-overflow-style.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441298.aspx)** and **[-ms-touch-action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh767313.aspx)** are the Internet Explorer equivalents for `-webkit-overflow scrolling:touch`. Check out the links attached for more information regarding syntax/usage.